# Runnable or Intent service

Tags: android, runnable, intentservice

I have read several articles regarding the background processes in android.
but I have situation where the background operation will take more than 30 seconds; example:

- Start activity
- click on button
- create runnable, call server for some data
  **30 seconds of (please wait message)**
- done, send message to the handler
- Screen orientation happens in the middle of the 30seconds...

I know that activity is destroyed and recreated (also the thread within is destoryed (make it static, handler to because of potencial memory leak).
   So, I will need to create runnable and call server again....

I read about intentService, and I understand that intentservice life cycle is the same as application's, so I assume i need to use this?

What is the best practice for handling screen orientation between these 30 seconds of `downloading/parsing/inserting` into `db` (transaction)? -> I dont want to use onConfigurationChanged() method.

What are your solutions for these kind of problems?

Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than associate your background operation with an Activity, I suggest you implement an [application object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html).  There can be only application object associated with any particular app, and it gets created before any Activity objects, and is independent of whatever activity objects are created/destroyed during the lifetime of your app.  I have an app where I get all my activity objects to register themselves with my application object.  If you do something similar, then it won't matter if any particular activity is destroyed and recreated due to a configuration change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Service for this, but better solution in my opinion will be having static Model class that will be updated by static handler that will do the work. When orientation occurred the activity may die but not the application. By the way you can add those lines to manifest and your activity will not die:

```
<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Counter_demoActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" >
```

But if you don't and your activity is dying and restarting you can update your state by reading the Static model class

Comment: Hm, you mean to have static class do the background work? Isnt that similar solution like the IntentService?

Comment: @Oggie Of Course not, IntentService is a Service so he have service life cycle. not application. You can say that service is bounded to application life cycle, but it's not always right.

Answer (score 0):

[JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) (minSdkVersion=21+) is a robust alternative to a runnable or Intent Service. It has retry logic built into it and doesn't suffer from the background restrictions on services in Android O.